# Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Generate_Exame, Line 6,The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I want insert in `question` table that has these columns

```
C#_T_F_Id, C#_T_F_Q, C#_T_F_Choices, C#_Mcq_Id, C#_MCQ_Q, C#_Choices
```

After execute `Generate_Exame` procedure what should I do :

```
create procedure Generate_Exame 
    @course_id int
as 
    if @course_id = 600
    begin
        insert into [dbo].[Question](C#_T_F_Id, C#_T_F_Q, C#_T_F_Choices,
                                     C#_Mcq_Id, C#_MCQ_Q, C#_Choices)
            select * 
            from
                (select top(3) 
                     T.C#_T_F_Id, T.C#_T_F_Q, T.C#_T_F_Choices
                 from 
                     C#_T_F T
                 order by
                     newid()) as t1
            union all
            select * 
            from
                (select top(7) 
                     C.C#_Mcq_Id C#_Q_id, C.C#_MCQ_Q C#_question, C.C#_Choices Choices              
                 from 
                     C#_MCQ C
                 order by
                     newid()) as t2)
    end
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You are declaring 6 columns for insert, but your `select` returns 5 columns only.

Comment: read the query again you will find that `Select` return 6 columns` T.C#_T_F_Id  ,T.C#_T_F_Q   , T.C#_T_F_Choices,C.C#_Mcq_Id C#_Q_id , C.C#_MCQ_QC#_question ,C.C#_Choices  Choices`

Comment: Union doesn't add the columns together, it adds the rows together, so now with your edit you are trying to insert 3 columns into 6 columns.

Comment: i wanna add these column  ``` T.C#_T_F_Id  ,T.C#_T_F_Q , T.C#_T_F_Choices,C.C#_Mcq_Id,C#_Q_id , C.C#_MCQ_Q,C#_question ,C.C#_Choices ``` to `question` table  that contain column that after union what query that should i write

Comment: It sounds like you want to join your 2 tables of random rows (instead of unioning them). However the best thing to do is show some sample data and expected results - that is the easiest way to clearly explain an SQL question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you want to:

- Insert data into a table from a combined result set.
- Combine two result sets side by side. The first one provides columns 1, 2, and 3, while the second one provides column 4, 5, and 6.
- On top of this both result sets (left and right) do not have the same lenght. One has 3 rows, while the other has 7 rows. I assume these numbers may vary.
- There's no set order for the rows on the left, or the rows on the right. You are producing them by ordering using a random UUID, so that can change every time you run the query.

In order to do this you need to produce a row number on each side. Then a simple full join will combine both result sets.

For example:

```
insert into [dbo].[Question] (
  C#_T_F_Id, C#_T_F_Q, C#_T_F_Choices,
  C#_Mcq_Id, C#_MCQ_Q, C#_Choices
)
select -- Step #4: produce combined rows, ready for insert
  a.T.C#_T_F_Id, a.T.C#_T_F_Q, a.T.C#_T_F_Choices,
  b.C#_Q_id, b.C#_question, b.Choices
from ( -- Step #1: Produce the left result set with row number (rn)
  select *, row_number() over(order by ord) as rn
  from (
    select top(3)
      T.C#_T_F_Id, T.C#_T_F_Q, T.C#_T_F_Choices, 
      newid() as ord
    from C#_T_F T 
    order by ord
  ) x
) a 
full join ( -- Step #2: Produce the right result set with row number (rn)
  select *, row_number() over(order by ord) as rn
  from (
    select top(7) 
      C.C#_Mcq_Id C#_Q_id, C.C#_MCQ_Q C#_question, C.C#_Choices Choices,
      newid() as ord
    from C#_MCQ C
    order by ord
  ) y
) b on a.rn = b.rn -- Step #3: Full join both result sets by row number (rn)
```

Comment: i edit my query read it again that will explain what i do ,What I want is  adding columns that after `union `too

Answer (score 0):

You are having six columns in the `INSERT` clause. But, you have only 3 columns coming out of the UNION query.

```sql
-- You are inserting 6 columns
insert into [dbo].[Question](C#_T_F_Id, C#_T_F_Q, C#_T_F_Choices,
                                     C#_Mcq_Id, C#_MCQ_Q, C#_Choices)

-- You are selecting only 3 columns.
            select * 
            from
                (select top(3) 
                     T.C#_T_F_Id, T.C#_T_F_Q, T.C#_T_F_Choices
                 from 
                     C#_T_F T
                 order by
                     newid()) as t1
            union all
            select * 
            from
                (select top(7) 
                     C.C#_Mcq_Id C#_Q_id, C.C#_MCQ_Q C#_question, C.C#_Choices Choices              
                 from 
                     C#_MCQ C
                 order by
                     newid()) as t2)
```

If you need to have 6 columns, you need to join the two SELECT statements in some way, based on JOIN condition.